# d3.json asynchronous solution

Tags: asynchronous, d3.js

I have a variable nest created from d3.json:

```
d3.json("api_all.php", function(data) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    e.date = parseDate(e.date);
    e.value = +e.close;
    e.stockName = e.stock_name;
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){
        return d.stockName;
      })
      .entries(data);
```

However I have another function down the code that needs to use the saved nest data:

```
var initialgraph = function(stockName) {
  /*Filter the data to include only stock of interest*/
  var selectStock = nest.filter(function(d) {
    return d.key == stockName;
  })

  var selectStockGroups = svg.selectAll(".stockGroups")
      .data(selectStock, function(d) {
        return d ? d.key : this.key;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "stockGroups")
      .each(function(d) {
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })])
      });

  var initialPath = selectStockGroups.selectAll(".rect")
      .data(function(d) {return d.value.year})
      .enter()
      .append("path")

  initialPath
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return valueLine(d.values)
    })
    .attr("class", "rect")

    /*Add Y Axis*/
    var yaxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
};
```

I have yet to find a solution for this problem...I was thinking 1) making the nest variable a global variable or  2) to include the initialgraph function as part of the d3.json data pull.

I have yet to find the right way to do #1 and #2 seems to cause a lot of additional problems for my code. So my bias is just finding a solution to doing #1. What are you suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `initialgraph` with the `nest` result as an argument. You only have a valid value in the nest variable when the callback is executing.

```
var initialgraph = function (stockName, nest) {
  // Filter the data to include only stock of interest
  var selectStock = nest.filter(function(d) { return d.key == stockName; });
  //....
};

d3.json("api_all.php", function(data) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    e.date = parseDate(e.date);
    e.value = +e.close;
    e.stockName = e.stock_name;
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d) { return d.stockName; })
      .entries(data);

  var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
  x.domain(xExtent);
  zoom.translateExtent([[x(xExtent[0]), -Infinity], [x(xExtent[1]), Infinity]])
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  yGroup.call(yAxis).select(".domain").remove();
  areaPath.datum(data);
  zoomRect.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);

  /*Build Dropdown Menu*/
  var stockDropDown = d3.select("#dropdown")
      stockDropDown
      .append("select")
      .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d){
          return d.key;
        })
        .text(function(d){
          return d.key;
        });
  initialgraph("KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.", nest);

});
```

If `initialgraph` is defined inside the callback you have no problem because it is a closure.

**Edit**

Like answered today about async functions, when `d3.json()` returns does not mean the call back is called/finished. Remove the `initialgraph()` call from line 134. And call it at the end of the callback.

**Edit 2**

Needed to look up an example for d3v4 and json to see what the interface is of the `d3.json()`. According to the docs it is using fetch and promises but apparently not. The real interface is

```
d3.json(url, function (error, data) {
    // process the data
});
```

Here is the complete code that shows at least the initial graph based on the json. I have not verified if it draws the correct graph.

Calling `y.domain()` in an `each()` call does not make sense. The max value is already determined based on the json `data`. Maybe it is an idea to use the extend of the `d.value`: `d3.extend(data, d=>d.value);`

The `updategraph()` now gets a valid `nest` value.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

/*Define the rect*/


/*Parse dates*/
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d"),
    formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

/*Set the ranges*/
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(2002, 0, 1), new Date(2003, 0, 1)])
    .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

/*Create axes*/
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var area = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveStepAfter)
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var areaPath = g.append("path")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

var yGroup = g.append("g");

var xGroup = g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 4, 8])
    .translateExtent([[-width, -Infinity], [2 * width, Infinity]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var zoomRect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(zoom);

g.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

/*Import Data from API*/
d3.json("api_all.php", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    e.date = parseDate(e.date);
    e.value = +e.close;
    e.stockName = e.stock_name;
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){
        return d.stockName;
      })
      .entries(data);

/*Scale range of the data*/
  var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
  x.domain(xExtent);
  zoom.translateExtent([[x(xExtent[0]), -Infinity], [x(xExtent[1]), Infinity]])
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  yGroup.call(yAxis).select(".domain").remove();
  areaPath.datum(data);
  zoomRect.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);

/*Build Dropdown Menu*/
  var stockDropDown = d3.select("#dropdown");
  stockDropDown
      .append("select")
      .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d){
          return d.key;
        })
        .text(function(d){
          return d.key;
        });
  stockDropDown.on("change", function() {
  var selectedStock = d3.select(this)
      .select("select")
      .property("value");
      updateGraph(selectedStock, nest);
  });

  initialgraph("KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.", nest);
});

/*Function to create initial graph*/
var initialgraph = function(stockName, nest) {
  /*Filter the data to include only stock of interest*/
  var selectStock = nest.filter(function(d) {
    return d.key == stockName;
  })


  var selectStockGroups = svg.selectAll(".stockGroups")
      .data(selectStock, function(d) {
        return d ? d.key : this.key;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "stockGroups")
    //   .each(function(d) {
    //          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    //   })
      ;

  var initialPath = selectStockGroups.selectAll(".rect")
      .data(function(d) {return d.value.year})
      .enter()
      .append("path")

  initialPath
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return valueLine(d.values)
    })
    .attr("class", "rect")

    /*Add Y Axis*/
    var yaxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
};

/*Create initial graph*/
//initialgraph("KYOKUYO CO.,LTD.");

/*Update the data*/
var updateGraph = function(stockName, nest) {
  var selectStock  = nest.filter(function(d) {
    return d.key == stockName;
  })
  var selectStockGroups = svg.selectAll(".stockGroups")
      .data(selectStock)
      .each(function(d) {
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })])
      });
      selectStockGroups.selectAll("path.rect")
        .data(function(d) {return d.value.year;}, function(d) {return d.key})
        .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return valueLine(d.values)
          })
}

/*Zoom function*/
function zoomed() {
  var xz = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
  xGroup.call(xAxis.scale(xz));
  areaPath.attr("d", area.x(function(d) { return xz(d.date); }));
}
```

Comment: I added the callback but I still get nest as undefined and now I have stockName as undefined as well...

Comment: @CharlesLee: without a complete working example we have to guess how you connect the parts together. I have no clue what your code is now.

Comment: @CharlesLee: for the data you can store dummy json at http://myjson.com/, edited the answer. The jsfiddle does not service the `api_all.php`

Comment: @CharlesLee: found the problem with the async load, it needed an `error` parameter.

Comment: so the y.domain suggestion is a separate suggestion?

Comment: @CharlesLee: only the last `y.domain` will be used so why call the other one, but you only have 1 stockGroup now in the nest, if I'm correct. And `data` does not change so all the call  have the same result.